# Angular Cookies don't work after ionic build

Tags: angularjs, cookies, ionic-framework, angular-cookies

I'm tring to store logged in user information in Angular Cookies. Strangely it work's well in browser when I do `ionic serve`. Also works in phone debug mode using `ionic run android -l-c --debug` usb debugging mode. But when I do `ionic build android` user information does not get stored in the $cookiestore.

I have referenced `<script src="lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>` in my index.html

Comment: Try gapDebug https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/ and you can see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `$cookieStore` with `localStorage`. It plays nice with both Android and iPhone. :)

```
$cookieStore.set() -> window.localStorage.setItem()
$cookieStore.get() -> window.localStorage.getItem()
$cookieStore.remove() -> window.localStorage.removeItem()
```